# add custom text field as configurable attribute for Magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, custom

We are preparing a tourism agency website and we have packages to sell online. These packages are inclusive of transfers, tours and hotel stays (eg. 3* - 4* - 5*), accomodation types (eg. sngl - dbl - trpl), adult quantity (eg. 1 - 2 - 3) etc.

We have managed to do them all by configurable attributes. But what we need is to get the names of these guests with a condition like if accomodation type is selected as DBL and adult quantity is selected as 2, we require 2 text fields asking the names and surnames of these adults. But if accomodation type is selected as TRPL and adult quantity is selected as 3, then we requre 3 text fields asking the names and surnames.

So as a conclusion these text fields must be dependant to these selections. We could not find a solution to add these custom text fields as a configurable attribute no matter we searched internet in every possible way. Please advise if there is a way and how.

Comment: to explain it briefly, we would like to include "text field" as a configurable attribute  like "drop-down" input type. Please help...